# Celery with django (gunicorn) and supervisor - how to give a unique name to each worker

Tags: django, celery, gunicorn, django-celery, supervisord

I've got 2 applications that start their own pool of workers.

So at first I thought that each pool should have a unique name only.
But I realise that there are still conflict between them.

For example sometimes the first pool of workers will receive a task and the error will be written by workers of the other pool.
Or if an other task arrive before the first one finished, it might not execute.

This is how my supervisor.conf looks like:

```
[program:celery-worker]
environment=DISPLAY=":1001",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=victoria.settings.production
directory = /home/victoria/current
command = /home/victoria/virtualenv/bin/celery -A victoria worker -l info --hostname=worker1@myhost
stdout_logfile = /home/victoria/celery-victoria-worker.log
stderr_logfile = /home/victoria/celery-worker.log
loglevel=warn


[program:api-worker]
environment = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.live
user = victoria
directory = /home/victoria/webapps/citysail/src
command = /home/victoria/webapps/citysail/.venv/bin/celery -A celery_app worker -l info -n api-worker --beat
stdout_logfile = /home/victoria/api-worker.log
loglevel = info
```

Do you have an idea how to generate a unique name for each worker?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your last paragraph means. There is no relationship between gunicorn workers and celery workers; they are both started completely independently.

Comment: You're right, I was just trying to find an explanation about why I've got 5 workers running "by default"